# How to show jquery popup only in one page or once?

Tags: jquery, javascript

i have this jquery popup but i need to show it only in the homepage. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#thover").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
    $("#tpopup").fadeOut();
    });


  $("#tclose").click(function(){
        $("#thover").fadeOut();
    $("#tpopup").fadeOut();
    });

});
```

This is the CSS:

```
<style>
```

## thover{

position:fixed;
  background:#000;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity: .6
  display:none;
}

## tpopup{

position:absolute;
  width:600px;
  height:836px;
  background:#eeeeee;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:10px 0;
  margin-left:-300px; /* width/2 + padding-left */
  margin-top:-418px; /* height/2 + padding-top */
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 #000;
  z-index: 9999;
  display:none;
}

## tclose{

position:absolute;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  right:-15px;
  top:-15px;
  border-radius:50%;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:8px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:'Arial Black', Arial, sans-serif;
  cursor:pointer;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 #000;
}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "show"? Your current code adds 2 click listeners, it shouldn't show anything by default

Comment: I am very bad at javascript, sorry! Still have much to learn. Here is the link to the website homepage:  http://www33.ecoar.com.br/

Comment: How the popup is working? Is it a plugin?

Comment: I got the script from this link: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-Add-a-popup-image-on-page-load-with-close-x-button-on-right-top-corner-in-HTML-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is add `display:none;`  to your CSS for both `#thover` & `#tpopup` so they are hidden by default.

Next you will want to use JS to find the URL of the page you are on and store this in a variable you can test against to determine if the pop-up should show.

Add the following to the jQuery function:

```
const pageURL = window.location.href;
```

Wrap everything else you already have in a conditional that checks if the page is Home:

```
if (pageURL === 'http://www33.ecoar.com.br/'){
...
}
```

Inside the conditional, add the following line of jQuery to show the pop-up when true:

```
jQuery("#tpopup, #thover").show();
```

The new completed JS for 'popup.js' will be:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    const pageURL = window.location.href;
        if (pageURL === 'http://www33.ecoar.com.br/') {
            jQuery("#tpopup, #thover").show();
            jQuery("#thover").click(function () {
                jQuery(this).fadeOut();
                jQuery("#tpopup").fadeOut();
            });
            jQuery("#tclose").click(function () {
                jQuery("#thover").fadeOut();
                jQuery("#tpopup").fadeOut();
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. It was a great idea to get the url. I would never thought of that. I followed your instructions, but i am getting a weird page when i set the css to display: none and in the other pages fo the site, i cant close the popup. I am going to edit the question to show the css.

Comment: Hm, looks like in the ```#thover``` selector you are missing a semicolon after ```opacity: .6``` try ```#thover{
position:fixed; background:#000; width:100%; height:100%; opacity: .6; display:none; }```

Comment: Man, youre right! Didnt see it. Thanks a lot for your help. Saved my ass :D. How can i get better at Javascript? I know it is annoying to ask for help so very often.

Comment: The more you work with a language, the more it sticks with you. Finding projects to work on to get your "practice" can be challenging when you're starting out. So I would recommend trying an online course that includes projects. Not only does it teach you the basics of the language, but it will show you how to put what you've learned to use. I personally recommend this one https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-javascript-course/. Good luck! If you could mark my answer as "Accepted" that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again! I will do what you suggested. Best regards!